# Heroku + Cloudflare DNS settings - 'No such app'

Tags: heroku, dns, cloudflare

The site is deployed with Heroku at [random-heroku-url]

If I visit my site via:

`https://www.[my-site].co.uk` > **this works!** :)

However, some friends have tried to access my site via:

`https://[my-site].co.uk` > **and this doesn't work!** :(

They get a Heroku `No such app` message.

I know this is to do with 'DNS' settings, 
... but I'm not great with 'DNS' settings.

My current DNS settings in Cloudflare are:

```
CNAME > [site-name].co.uk > [random-heroku-url]
CNAME > www > [random-heroku-url]
TXT > [site-name].co.uk > [google authentication code]
```

Anything I should, delete or add?

Also, how long do DNS changes take? Will it change straight away if it's working?

Or is it my Heroku Domain settings:

```
www.[site-name].co.uk > [random-heroku-url] > ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, by writing my question I found the answer.

I changed my Heroku Domain settings:

```
[site-name].co.uk > [random-heroku-url-1] > ok
www.[site-name].co.uk > [random-heroku-url-2] > ok
```

Then updated my Cloudflare settings to:

```
CNAME > [site-name].co.uk > [random-heroku-url-1]
CNAME > www > [random-heroku-url-2]
TXT > [site-name].co.uk > [google authentication code]
```

Now it works fine :)